# How can I upload a file to a CouchDB instance as an attachment?

Tags: html, couchdb

I have an HTML form that I can use to create documents with text only content currently. However, I want to be able to upload file data through the form as well.

How can I do this? Here is the form I am using so far

```
<form class="form-horizontal well" id="submitform" name="submitform">
  <label class="control-label" for="brand">Brand</label>
          <label class="control-label" for="link">Any other thoughts?</label>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <textarea class="input" rows="3" name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="submit" class="btn"/>
            </div>
          </div>

          <label class="control-label" for="picture[]">Got a Picture?</label>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="file" name="_attachments" id="picture" accept="image/*" multiple/>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I tried using some AJAX to upload the file, but I was only able to the upload the filename as an attachment, not the actual contents.

```
$.couch.db("couchclothes").saveDoc
  (
    {
      type:   $('#type').val(), 
      brand:  $('#brand').val(), 
      fit:    $('#fit').val(),
      color:  $('#color').val(),
      link:   $('#link').val(),
      notes:  $('#notes').val()
    },  
    {
      success: function(data) 
      { 
        alert("Saved data ok."); 
        var id = data.id;
        var rev = data.rev;

        // send a PUT request here
      }
    }  
  );
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd also be interested in how to do a classic form POST with field and files.

However if it's fine to do the data and file upload in two separate steps (and to answer your question) check this solution that works with XHR2 browsers: [How to upload a file (attachment) from the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864257/how-to-upload-a-file-attachment-from-the-browser)